# Data table fread with zip file in other directory with spaces in the name

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to read a csv in a zip file by using the command `fread("unzip -cq file.zip")` which works perfectly when the file is in my working directory.
But when I try the command by specifying the path of the file without changing the directory say `fread("unzip -cq C:/Users/My user/file.zip")` I get an error saying the following `unzip:  cannot find either C:/Users/My or C:/Users/My.zip`

The reason why this happens is that there are spaces in my path but what would be the workaround?

The only option that I have thought is to just change to the directory where each file is located and read it from there but this is not ideal.

Comment: The arguement to `fread` in this case is a system command. So the file path should probably have ` \ ` instead of `/`. Try : `fread("unzip -cq C:\\Users\\Myuser\\file.zip")`

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work either for me.

Comment: Are there spaces in your path?

Comment: Yes there are. The `setwd(path)` works fine though.

Comment: Try running the unzip command from the terminal. What happens if you do that?

Comment: I realized that the issue is not the path as such but the fact that there are spaces in my path name as @AEF correctly pointed out!

Comment: I use shQuote to wrap the path before making the command for fread... it's worked so far on Windows fwiw.

Comment: @Frank please put it as an answer so I can close it, thank you it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `shQuote` for this, like...

```
fread_zip = function(fp, silent=FALSE){
  qfp = shQuote(fp)

  patt = "unzip -cq %s"

  thecall = sprintf(patt, qfp)
  if (!silent) cat("The call:", thecall, sep="\n")

  fread(thecall)
}
```

Defining a pattern and then substituting in with `sprintf` can keep things readable and easier to manage. For example, I have a similar wrapper for `.tar.gz` files (which apparently need to be unzipped twice with a `|` pipe between the steps).

---

If your zip contains multiple csvs, `fread` isn't set up to read them all (though there's [an open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2582)). My workaround for that case currently looks like...

```
library(magrittr)
fread_zips = function(fp, unzip_dir = file.path(dirname(fp), sprintf("csvtemp_%s", sub(".zip", "", basename(fp)))), silent = FALSE, do_cleanup = TRUE){
  # only tested on windows
  # fp should be the path to mycsvs.zip
  # unzip_dir should be used only for CSVs from inside the zip

  dir.create(unzip_dir, showWarnings = FALSE)

  # unzip

  unzip(fp, overwrite = TRUE, exdir = unzip_dir)

  # list files, read separately
  # not looking recursively, since csvs should be only one level deep

  fns = list.files(unzip_dir)

  if (!all(tools::file_ext(fns) == "csv")) stop("fp should contain only CSVs")

  res = lapply(fns %>% setNames(file.path(unzip_dir, .), .), fread)

  if (do_cleanup) unlink(unzip_dir, recursive = TRUE)

  res
}
```

So, because we're not passing a command-line call directly to fread, there's no need for `shQuote` here. I wrote and used this function yesterday, so there are probably still some oversights or bugs.

The magrittr `%>%` pipe part could be written as `setNames(file.path(unzip_dir, fns), fns)` instead.

Comment: The first part I got, the second I have to try out! Thank you in any case!

Comment: Yeah, just figured I'd post it in case it's useful to someone else eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the location to a variable and use paste to call the zip file like below:

```
myVar<-"C:/Users/Myuser/"
fread(paste0("unzip -cq ",myVar,"file.zip"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works in the case where there are no spaces in the path (myVar in your example) but it still fails for the case where there are spaces.